# What is wrong with my Bootstrap carousel code?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I'm currently working on Angela Yu Web Development Course and I'm learning Bootstrap carousels. I wrote the code and ran it on Codeply and it worked fine. Then I implemented the code according to my own HTML and `next` or `previous` buttons are not functional anymore. They also look "wrong" visually with strange borders and backgrounds. I double checked the Bootstrap documentation and couldn't find why this was happening. Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <!-- External CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

  <!--  Google fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@400;700&family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;700;900&family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
    
  <!-- Font awesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3f441d9c50.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<section id="testimonials">
<div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2> I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on
            TinDog. Woof. </h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile" />
          <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've
            found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
          <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
 </button>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
```

```
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 0 15%;
}

/* Features section */

#features {
  padding: 7% 15%;
}

.features-box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
}

.features-h3 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.features-p {
  color: #8f8f8f;
}

.features-icon {
  color: #a38a5c;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.features-icon:hover {
  color: #985d0f;
}
/* 
.features-container {
  margin: 0 5%;
} */

#slogan-h1 {
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

#title {
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/vVpW8H1/gold-bg-canva.png) no-repeat;
  width: auto;
  height: 900px;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: outset white 5px;

  /*   golden themed color
  color: #a38a5c; */
}

/* Navigation Bar */

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Jost", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  /* These are not functional because I used logo instead of text. */
}

.navbar {
  align-items: start;
  padding-bottom: 4.5rem;
}

.navbar-content-div {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#my-navbar-container {
  padding: 1% 3%;
}

/* Download buttons */

.title-button {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.title-button-grid {
  margin-right: 10%;
}

/* Testimonial Section */

#testimonials {
  padding: 7% 15%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(163, 138, 92, 1);
  color: #fff;
}

.testimonial-image {
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}

#press {
  background: rgba(163, 138, 92, 1);
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.press-logo {
  width: 10%;
  margin: 20px 20px 50px;
}
```

[image: screenshot of the buttons]

Edit: The problem was that I was trying to load Bootstrap 4 but writing the HTML code for Bootstrap 5. It's solved now.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more code. The code above doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Check your external CSS file, I think some styles are adding into the `prev` and `next` buttons.

Comment: The code above is the same as before. There are probably some styles inside the `styles.css` that are causing problems. **Edit your question once again and add CSS from the `styles.css`.**

Comment: Added `styles.css`. Also, the main problem is that the buttons are not functional. I can deal with the visuals later but my main purpose is to get it to function properly for now.

Comment: The problem is the Boostrap version. It is 4.x but your carousel code looks like the latest version codes. See the modified codes below.!

Comment: Why have you tagged version 5 when you're loading version 4 (and an extremely _old_ version 4.0.0 at that)? You're using version 5 syntax. Be sure to follow the correct docs for your version.

Answer (score 1):

Realy if you want to use Bootstrap version 4.x, then the carousel code should be like this,

```
<div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <h2> I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on
                TinDog. Woof. </h2>
              <img class="testimonial-image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/la.jpg" alt="dog-profile" />
              <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've
                found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
              <img class="testimonial-image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/ny.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
              <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" href="#testimonial-carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" href="#testimonial-carousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
     </button>
        </div>
```

Buttons should have **`href=`** instead of **`data-target=`**

And wherever `-bs-` was added, just remove that! (e.g., `data-bs-ride="false"`)